# Setup tomcat and Netbeans to run web application

Tags: java, tomcat, netbeans

I have installed Tomcat 6 and Netbeans 6.5.1. I have created a web application I

```
In-place deployment at D:\Work\Projects\JAVA\Test\build\web
deploy?config=file:/C:/Users/Sid/AppData/Local/Temp/context4479714370270325800.xml&path=/Test
FAIL - Failed to deploy application at context path /Test
D:\Work\Projects\JAVA\Test\nbproject\build-impl.xml:545: The module has not been deployed.
BUILD FAILED (total time: 0 seconds)
```

Comment: Why I am getting this error. How can I resolve it?

Comment: Can you paste snippet of this `build-impl.xml:545` file?

Comment: <nbdeploy clientUrlPart="${client.urlPart}" debugmode="false" forceRedeploy="${forceRedeploy}"/>

Comment: There's some problem with your web.xml file. Please make sure everything fine in web.xml file. Display the Apache_Tomcat_Log message if any.

Comment: Show tomcat output and tomcat log.